# Laravel Auth::attempt and Hashing password

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, security

Due to limitation of internet connection in my area, I decided to not using the laravel/ui package.

My problem is that the Auth::attempt is not working properly. The hash keeps changing so the hashed password do not match. Help.

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email'=> $request->input('email'), 'password'=> $request->input('password')])
```

Answer (score 0):

use Hash;
Hash::make($request->input('input'));

Answer (score 0):

First of all query to get user

```
$user  = User::where('email' , $request->input('email') ) ->first();
```

Then check hashed password with input password

```
$password  = $request->input('password');
if (!Hash::check($password, $user->password)) { 
    //login failed 
    // return proper message to user 
    // return back();
}
Auth::login($user);
```